# Opendaylight shows wrong topology

Tags: karaf, openflow, sdn, opendaylight

I' m working on an SDN lab, I have 3 interconnected switches (2NETFPGA+1Open Vswitch) with a host connected to each. I'm setting OpenDayLight as a controller but the problem is that I can not get the controller to see the topology: It just shows the switches! no hosts ! no connection between switches!

I have installed these features in karaf: 
odl-l2switch-all and
odl-dlux-all

Thanks for your help! 
Regards

Comment: Could it be the case that it's dropping all the packages when you're sending the pings and because of that the switches are not actually connecting to the hosts? I would recommend to make sure from the console that you can actually talk between the hosts before trying to see the connections in the UI.

Comment: Hey, Pings between hosts do not reach. Normal ! the controller doesn't know about these hosts! I have tried with floodlight in this same topology configuration and it works just great !

Comment: Mmh how do you create the topology? Are you using mininet? And yes, floodlight is normally a very friendly controller, I have tried Ryu and it was a nightmare :(

Comment: My topology is hardware based. 2 Netfpga 1G switches and an Openvswitch. Is there a problem between Netfpga and Opendaylight ? 
Because I get some warnings on the Netfpgas saying: |datapath|WARN|recieved stats request of unkown type 12 ? Is openflow 1.0 enabled by default on ODL ? The problem is only with NetFpga because I can see the host connected to OVS !

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem once. But in my case, displaying the hosts on the dlux gui was more of a priority and so i added a lower priority flow entry to the switches for action NORMAL. I know this is a work around, but it helps based on the need.